# SML and church numerals

Tags: sml

I have an assignment where I need to implement church numerals in SML using the datatype: datatype 'a church = C of ('a -'a) * 'a -> 'a

I have to write the function create :int -> 'a church and a function churchToint
So far I have the following code:

```
datatype 'a church = C of ('a -> 'a) * 'a -> 'a
val ZERO = C(fn (f,x) => x)
fun subCreate 0 (f,x) = x
    | subCreate n (f,x) = f (subCreate (n-1) (f,x))
fun create n = C(fn (f,x) => subCreate n (f,x));
fun churchToInt cn = cn (fn x => x + 1) 0;
```

I know I am pretty close. Can you please assist me in implementing this correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you are quite close. There are only two minor mistakes in your churchToInt function:

1. You're not unpacking the church numeral. I.e. you treat your argument `cn` like a function, but `churchToInt` should accept a `C` *containing* a function, not a function itself. So change it to `fun churchToInt (C cn) =`, to unpack the function via pattern matching.
2. You're applying two arguments to the function using curry style, but `C` has been defined to contain a function taking a tuple. So instead of `cn (fn x => x+1) 0`, write `cn ((fn x => x+1), 0)`.

With these two changes your code works fine.

Comment: I did that however is still get churchToInt:int church -> int instead of 'a church. And in addition, when I run for example:
create 5; I get: "Warning type cars not generalized because of value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,....)
val it = C fn : ?.X1 church "

Comment: @tester: Of course the type is `int church -> int`. If the type were `'a church -> int`, you wouldn't be allowed to pass in a function of type `int -> int`. If the assignment really requires you to define a function of type `'a church -> int`, I dare say it's not solvable - at least not with the given type definition.

Comment: but what about the function create, I mean it's working for example churchToInt (create 5) returns 5 but whenever I run create it keeps giving me that weird error

Comment: @tester: It's not an error. It's a warning. If you want to, you can make it go away by giving it an explicit type. E.g. `val myCn : int church = create 5` will compile and run without warning.